# Can We Create On Delete Cascade on exiting foreign Key

Tags: sql-server

Can we create `On Delete Cascade` on an existing Foreign Key?

I know we can create from SQL design of table going to relationships But I want to do this with the script query?

I also not want to drop foreign key first and then create the foreign key with on delete cascade, I not want this.

Comment: What is an "exiting" key?

Comment: this is existing key

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HL7_Rx_Resident_NonVerified]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_HL7_Rx_Resident_NonVerified] FOREIGN KEY([MedicationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[RxOrder_Resident_NonVerified] ([Id])

Comment: Now I want to make it on delete cascade without dropping and recreating and without using the sql relation design view

Comment: Exactly why don't you want to drop and re-add the constraint? Perhaps you could add a new constraint with the cascade option and then drop the old one.

Comment: its very connected and complex schema, dropping constraint can cause lot of other things to break so that is why I not want this

Comment: I believe adding the new constraint, dropping the old constraint, and renaming the new constraint to the old name will not break anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `ALTER CONSTRAINT` syntax. If you have created a `CONSTRAINT` and you need to change it, you need to `DROP` the `CONSTRAINT` and then `CREATE` it again; there is no work around for this.

In this case, using the definition in the comments, you would need to do:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HL7_Rx_Resident_NonVerified] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_HL7_Rx_Resident_NonVerified];
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HL7_Rx_Resident_NonVerified] WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_HL7_Rx_Resident_NonVerified]
    FOREIGN KEY ([MedicationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[RxOrder_Resident_NonVerified] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
GO
```

Comment: I already said I know this and this is not solution I need

Comment: @AliHussain it is the solution you **need**, it's just not the solution you *want*. These are different things. The fact you want to be able to use `ALTER CONSTRAINT` syntax doesn't change the fact that you can't; it doesn't exist.

Comment: ok it not exists answer give me confidence that there is only one way and I have to go by that way only
thanks